# How to separate fats from liquid and where do unsaturated fats go?

Tags: fat

If you have some liquid from roasting, stew or soup etc and you want to separate the fat, I believe the normal methods is to get a spoon and remove it from the top or let it come to room temperature, solidify and then remove it.

If it solidifies and you remove it, isn't it only the saturated fat you are removing while the unsaturated fats stay behind?  How do you remove unsaturated fats also?

Comment: Problem is, unsaturated fat mix way easier with saturated fat than water. So when they make contact they won't have any separation. Think about petroleum industry to get an idea how hard it is to separate one form of oil from another.

Answer (score 5):

Saturated fats (eg the white part of a steak or chop) are generally solid **at room temperature** while unsaturated (eg olive oil) are not. Generally the advice for getting fats out of soups and stews is to chill it so it all solidifies. Since it floats whether it is solid or not, there are also techniques like skimming, absorbing with a paper towel or bread, etc. (See [How can I remove excess fat from stews or soups without refrigerating?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4161/how-can-i-remove-excess-fat-from-stews-or-soups-without-refrigerating) for examples.)

The temperature at which something solidifies is a [poor way to test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturated_fat) whether a fat is saturated or unsaturated, and it's not an important distinction really. If it's important to you to get **all** the fat from something, then chilling and waiting is probably the most effective way. If you don't have time for that then you either eat a little fat (which for most people is fine) or you make a different dish.